# Where is local log file located for Google App Engine Java app

Tags: google-app-engine

I am writing to the log with my Google App Engine (GAE) app but I cannot find where it is being stored. I have read a lot of posts on Stackoverflow but none of them indicate where to find this. I'm running my app in IntelliJ, using Gradle and IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

The logs are not stored in a plain text file, they're stored as an SQLite database. From [Local Development Server Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command):

> `--logs_path=...`
>
> By default, the logs for the local development server are stored in
>   memory only. Specify this option when you run the local development
>   server to store the logs into a file, which makes the logs available
>   across server restarts. You must specify the directory path and name
>   to a SQLite database file. A SQLite database file is created with the
>   specified name if the file does not already exist. For example:
>   `--logs_path=/home/logs/boglogs.db`

Not sure about the in-memory storage, though, I can see my devserver writing to a default db file even without setting this option explicitly (on Linux, using `lsof` on the PyCharm-driven devserver's PID):

```
$ lsof -p 22811 | grep -i log
python2.7 22811 username    4ur  REG       8,3 1648899072   1705871 /tmp/appengine.<app_name>.username/logs.db
python2.7 22811 username   24u   REG       8,3       3608   1712816 /tmp/appengine.<app_name>.username/logs.db-journal
$ file /tmp/appengine.<app_name>.username/logs.db
/tmp/appengine.<app_name>.username/logs.db: SQLite 3.x database
```

**Note:** the above are for the Python devserver, Java is a bit different, but on Linux the same method may be usable to identify the location and type of the default file holding logs. The `--generated_dir` option *might* be the one to use to overwrite the default location. From [Command-Line Arguments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server#command-line-arguments):

> `--generated_dir=...`
>
> Set the directory where generated files are created.

Comment: As you mentioned, this really only seems to apply to python. I'm looking for a Java solution. I couldn't find one so in the end I created my own log file when the app is being debugged locally. Still, if someone does find a workable solution for Java, that would be appreciated. I'm really surprised that Google would address this for python but not for Java.

Comment: Cloud Support here!  I filed a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74417976) that you can follow for updates.